# CSS Relative Positioning Issue

Tags: html, css

To move the position of an image to a certain part of my website, ive put the image in a div tag and used relative position to get it to the place i want it. This works fine for where i want the image to be positioned however there is a downside that it leaves white space behind where it previously use to be and in that space nothing is occupied and it makes the website look ugly. Is there a way to remove that space that it left behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated above, you should position the element absolute instead. When positioning relative, the element is still within the document flow and therefore occupies its original place in the document. Positioning absolute will remove the element from the flow and make the space available for other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning instead.